# Double y axis for multiple columns in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I would like to display the following dataframe in barchart but with double `y axis`, I want to show `area`s columns on left side and `price`s columns on right side:

```
             area1      area2        price1      price2
level               
first       263.16      906.58      10443.32     35101.88
second      6879.83    14343.03      2077.79     4415.53
third      31942.75    60864.24       922.87     1774.47
```

I tried with code below, it works but only display left side.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation=45, fontproperties="SimHei")
plt.xlabel("")
plt.legend()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, one way could be this, but you have to "play" a bit with the values of width and position of the ticks:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
ax2 = ax.twinx() 

width = 0.1

df.area1.plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=0 )
df.area2.plot(kind='bar', color='orange', ax=ax, width=width, position=1)
df.price1.plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, width=width, position=2)
df.price2.plot(kind='bar', color='green', ax=ax2, width=width, position=3)

ax.set_ylabel('Area')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.legend(["Area1", "Area2"], bbox_to_anchor=(0.8,1.0))
ax2.legend(["Price1", "Price2"], bbox_to_anchor=(0.9,1.0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Another way is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
ax2 = ax.twinx() 
# ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45) # Rotation 45 degrees

width = 0.1
ind = np.arange(len(df))

ax.set_ylabel('Area')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.set_xlabel('Level')
ax.bar(ind, df.area1, width, color='red', label='area1')
ax.bar(ind + width, df.area2, width, color='orange', label='area2')
ax2.bar(ind + 2*width, df.price1, width, color='blue', label='price1')
ax2.bar(ind + 3*width, df.price2, width, color='green', label='price2')

ax.set(xticks=(ind + 1.5*width), xticklabels=df.index, xlim=[2*width - 1, len(df)])
ax.legend(["Area1", "Area2"], bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
ax2.legend(["Price1", "Price2"], bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.87))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, how could rotate `xticks` with 45 degree? I try with `plt.xticks(rotation=45)` or `ax.xticks(rotation=45)`, both doesn't work.

Comment: @ahbon I have updated the answer with another solution, please check it :)

Comment: @ahbon for rotation of 45 degrees of `xticks`, use `ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45)` in the second option

Comment: How about this one? `ax.set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=45)`, I have tried but `ax2`'s `xticks` position was not as expected, all was put on the left side. The first one is OK, it's weird.

Comment: `ax.set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=45)` works for me too